# How to run two instances of the same Play! Framework application?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I am trying to run two instances of the same Play application in order to transparently upgrade the application in the future.

When I launch the first instance, everything goes fine obviously. When I launch the `start 9525` command to launch the second instance of the application on port 9525, I get the following error:

```
Play server process ID is 8909
This application is already running (Or delete .../RUNNING_PID file)
```

Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Which HTTP server you finally choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This Play's doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/HTTPServer) already describes using of Apache for '*transparent upgrading*'. In general you need to start two instances in two **separate** folders

At the beginning:

1. Create `dist` package inside your folder with apps sources
2. Unzip it to some subfolder ie. `instance1`
3. Start `instance1` on desired port for an example `9998` it will be your *every-day* instance

After changes, when you want to redeploy app transpalently:

1. Push changes to server (assuming that you are using some versioning system, ie. git)
2. Create `dist` and unzip it to **other** folder ie. `instance2`
3. Start it on the **other** port ie. `9999`
4. Stop application in folder `instance1`
5. Copy unzipped dist from `instance2` to `instance1`
6. Start application in `instance1` and stop application on `instance2`
7. Repeat this procedure every time you need to redeploy with new changes.

Of course creating simple shell script which will perform all steps at once will be great helper for you.

**TIP:**

To avoid often re-deployment, especially when you need just to replace/modify some **public**  and **static** contents like CSS or images, you can also use Apache common `vhost` for handling these resources. Just create a `vhost` for some folder as a subdomain ie. `http://static.domain.tld` or better with separate domain: `http://my-cdn.tld` so you can use a path like:

```
<img src="http://static.domain.tld/images/photo.png" alt="" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="/public/images/photo.png" alt="" />
```

The benefits:

- You don't need to redeoploy the app to change these files.
- You don't send the cookies, which are mostly redundant for public assets (if vhost's domain is other than main project)
- You can use HTTP server's configuration for setting cache tags (performance!)
- You are sharing statics automatically between all instances.
- You don't waste JVM resources for serving the pictures :) I noticed that, although Play's default server can be really fast, serving static contents with simple HTTP server is probably faster...

And finally, from my experience, nginx is faster than Apache. So if only task for HTTP server in your case is load-balancing the Play's apps, consider using nginx it's just lighter.

Comment: Perfect answer! I was missing the part where the two instances should be launched from two different folders which now makes sense.

Comment: Check my edit with tip, can be useful for you, especially when you are using HTTP server now.